# How to remove text in textbox upon clicking and get back the text after removing the cursor inside the textbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have code below that works so when I click my search textbox, the text will be cleared and the forecolor becomes black.

```
Private Sub txbSearch_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles txbSearch.MouseClick
        txbSearch.Text = ""
        txbSearch.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End Sub
```

My problem is when I am done using the search box I want the text set back to "Search" and forecolor set to gray. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to explain your problem. Writing code alone won't work.

Comment: How does your search get executed?  Maybe from a Button handler?  When the search is complete, reset your TextBox.  You haven't shown us enough code to properly help you.

Comment: Why would you expect this to happen automatically? You need to write code to make it happen that will run when you perform a search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you're asking for, and I hope this is what you need :

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseClick
    If TextBox1.Text = "Search" Then
        TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        TextBox1.Text = "Search"
        TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Gray
    End If
End Sub
```

But please try explain it better next time for the others also to understand and maybe get a benefit from it.. **Happy Coding :)**

Comment: Wow..! You get my point Mousa Alfhaily it's working exactly want I want. Thank you.! Sorry for my explanation. I can't express my totally the problem. but thank you that you get it..